# Create new column based on multiple conditions of existing column while manipulating existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python/pandas coming from an R background. I am having trouble understanding how I can manipulate an existing column to create a new column based on multiple conditions of the existing column. There are 10 different conditions that need to met but for simplicity I will use a 2 case scenario.

In R:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame("Date" = c("2020-07-01", "2020-07-15"))
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df$Fiscal <- ifelse(day(df$Date) > 14, 
                paste0(year(df$Date),"-",month(df$Date) + 1,"-01"),
                paste0(year(df$Date),"-",month(df$Date),"-01")
              )
df$Fiscal <- as.Date(df$Fiscal, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

In Python I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = {'Date': ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], yearfirst = True, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df.loc[df['Date'].dt.day > 14, 
       'Fiscal'] = "-".join([dt.datetime.strftime(df['Date'].dt.year), dt.datetime.strftime(df['Date'].dt.month + 1),"01"])

df.loc[df['Date'].dt.day <= 14, 
       'Fiscal'] = "-".join([dt.datetime.strftime(df['Date'].dt.year), dt.datetime.strftime(df['Date'].dt.month),"01"])
```

If I don't convert the 'Date' field it says that it expects a string, however if I do convert the date field, I still get an error as it seems it is applying to a 'Series' object.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'Series' object
```

I understand I may have some terminology or concepts incorrect and apologize, however the answers I have seen dealing with creating a new column with multiple conditions do not seem to be manipulating the existing column they are checking the condition on, and simply taking on an assigned value. I can only imagine there is a more efficient way of doing this that is less 'R-ey' but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't intended as a full answer, just as an *illustration* how `strftime` works: `strftime` is a method of a `date(time)` object that takes a format-string as argument:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = {'Date': ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], yearfirst = True, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

s = [dt.date(df['Date'][i].year, df['Date'][i].month + 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
     for i in df['Date'].index]

print(s)
```

Result:

```
['2020-08-01', '2020-08-01']
```

Again: No full answer, just a hint.

**EDIT**: You can vectorise this, for example by:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = {'Date': ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], yearfirst=True, format='%Y-%m-%d')

df['Fiscal'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda d: dt.date(d.year, d.month, 1)
                                          if d.day < 15 else
                                          dt.date(d.year, d.month + 1, 1))
print(df)
```

Result:

```
        Date      Fiscal
0 2020-07-01  2020-07-01
1 2020-07-15  2020-08-01
```

Here I'm using an on-the-fly `lambda` function. You could also do it with an externally defined function:

```
def to_fiscal(date):
    if date.day < 15:
        return dt.date(date.year, date.month, 1)
    return dt.date(date.year, date.month + 1, 1)

df['Fiscal'] = df['Date'].apply(to_fiscal)
```

In general vectorisation is better than looping over rows because the looping is done on a more "lower" level and that is much more efficient.

Comment: I originally used strftime because I thought it was converting the date to a string, and it seemed I needed to use a string to do the join. But now I am not sure if it is even needed. Why not just loop over every row in the column, obtain the individual value, use this with compare statements and then create the new value from there? What advantage do these 'vectorized' functions have? So far it is not intuitive to me like R vectorized functions

Answer (score 0):

Until someone tells me otherwise I will do it this way. If there's a way to do it vectorized (or just a better way in general) I would greatly appreciate it

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = {'Date': ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], yearfirst=True, format='%Y-%m-%d')

test_list = list()
for i in df['Date'].index:
   
    mth = df['Date'][i].month
    yr = df['Date'][i].year
    dy = df['Date'][i].day
    
    if(dy > 14):
        new_date = dt.date(yr, mth + 1, 1)
    else:
        new_date = dt.date(yr, mth, 1)
      
    test_list.append(new_date)
    
df['New_Date'] = test_list
```

Comment: I don't understand this but thanks for the answer and I'll try to understand it later

Comment: I **accidentally** edited your post. I hope it doesn't get approved. Sorry! See the edit of my post.